# Display problem with TeX codes in browsers

Tags: gnome, latex

After unsuccessfully installing latex packages `thmtools` under gnome environment on my work station, mainly because of lack of root access, I keep receiving the following error in displays of equations in any browsers

```
Failed to parse(unknown function '\begin')
```

I am looking for an easy solution, without invoking the operations required root access.

Answer (score 1):

I will not ask why you do not have root access to your workstation.

If you want to have it installed from the repository, somebody has to have and needs to run

```
sudo apt-get install texlive-latex-extra
```

where the package `thmtools` is found.

But I fail to see how that **alone** would enable you to see LaTeX-rendered equations in browsers unless using **MathJax** or something similar.

---

**Edit**

At least on Chemistry.SE, the array environment `\begin{array}` has to be escaped with a leading backslash:`\\begin{array}`. Actually, you have to escape every backslash.

Comment: The work station is employer's property. Probably it is not the cause, but indeed the equations are written in MathJax format.